# Is there anything I can do to make it easier to remove plugs from receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

Is there anything I can do to make it easier to pull plug ins out of the wall sockets?  All of the wall sockets in the kitchen make it very difficult to pull the plug in out of the wall receptacle.  The toaster, the coffee maker, the can opener, the microwave, etc., are all difficult to pull out of the wall sockets in the kitchen.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Stick it in, pull it out, stick it in, pull it out, repeat.  They always start out "tight", and will loosen up as they get broken in. They're required to have a certain amount of "holding strength", so that plugs don't easily fall out. To insure they maintain this strength for the longest time possible, they are designed to start off a bit stronger than needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this attachments to make plug easier to pull out:

[image]

[Source](http://www.co-opxest.com/Store/product-is-LH1036)

These appear to stick onto your existing plugs.

You can get new plugs with a built in handle:

[image]

[UK Source](http://www.lighting-direct.co.uk/13-Amp-Easy-Pull-White-Plug.html)

but these would require you to rewire all your appliances. This is perfectly safe if done properly, so if you don't feel confident in doing it yourself you should be able to get an electrician to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend in part on where you are in the world. Sockets in the UK can be very tight when new, but if you open them up you can often loosen the metal contacts so they don't grip the plug as tightly. I would imagine sockets in other countries will also have similar adjustments possible.

**Make sure you turn off current at the breaker/fuse box first!**

In general, though, I wouldn't advise doing this as it does increase the risk that you will get a bad electrical connection, which could lead to arcing and fire. This is still a low risk, so don't panic, but in general repeated plugging-in and removal will loosen and weaken the socket over time.

I do not unplug appliances in my kitchen, but just turn them off with the switches, which are designed for repeated use.

Comment: I find even in the US/CDN, the new TR outlets tend to be very tight too

Comment: In the US, this is typical of new Heavy Duty sockets. It's a sign your contractor didn't skimp on the most used sockets in the house and use light duty lamp sockets everywhere if this is a new dwelling.

Comment: Arcing is not the only hazard with bad connections.  Resistance creates heat, which creates more resistance. It's a vicious cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you buy a power strip.

If you are concerned that the appliances are disconnected when you're absent, then you can turn off the switch on the power strip.  And, no more plugging and unplugging.

Comment: Good idea. But if this is for toaster or other either high-current or large-motor (e.g., vacuum cleaner) appliances, make sure it is ONLY a *power strip* and **NOT** a *surge protector*.

Answer (score 0):

This will sound strange however I've discovered that if I unplug the appliance and simply whip the plug prongs using my index finger and my thumb the plug goes in and out smoothly.  I now do this every time I plug in and unplug our appliances and it works like a charm for me, go figure?

Answer (score 0):

Thrre are many plug pullers on the market, for this purpose. This one does not require gluing or replacing plugs.

[image]

This one is on ebay, but amazon have them too. And so do shops specialising in disablity products.

I suspect you problem is that you dont have enough sockets for all your aplliances. Get an electrician to replace them with 4 or 6 way strip with switches.